# 'User' object has no attribute 'mutual_guilds'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Im trying to make a feature that would allow users to message me via dms to the bot, thats working fine, but I have an issue with user.mutual_guilds, it says `'User' object has no attribute 'mutual_guilds'`, but on docs it has [mutual_guilds](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.mutual_guilds) in the user.
Heres a simple version that gives same error

```python
async def create_dm_channel(msg):
    print(msg.author.mutual_guilds)
    return


@bot.listen()
async def on_message(msg):
    if msg.guild is None:
        await create_dm_channel(msg)
        return
```

Comment: You can read that it's new in version 1.7 which haven't been released yet, you can install it directly from github to get the dev version

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński ohh thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar problem, not sure if you've figured it out but the `mutual_guilds` part of `discord.py` had a change in the update to version 1.7.

If you use pip you can update with the command `pip install --upgrade discord` otherwise you can download from source https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py